# I have a ValueError while using Jupyter Notebook and need help to find out why I get this error and how to fix it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

When I run this code:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor 
melbourne_model = DecisionTreeRegressor() 
melbourne_model.fit(X, y)
```

I get this output:

`ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32').`

This error points to the line where it says `melbourne_model.fit(X, y)`.
I want the code to fit the model with `X` and `y` so I can make future predictions of houses in Melbourne based on a few variables I input such as year built, land area, rooms/bedrooms, location, etc. Right now I can't do that because of this error.

I think it is because the `X` and `y` aren't NumPy Arrays and when I use `np.asarray()` and put what I want to turn into a NumPy Array, it doesn't work. I know this because when I write `type(X)` or `type(y)`, I get `pandas.core.series.Series`.

The whole code to my file:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
melbourne_file_path = 'melb_data.csv\\melb_data.csv'
melbourne_data = pd.read_csv(melbourne_file_path)
np.asarray(melbourne_data.Price)
y = melbourne_data.Price
melbourne_predictors = ['Rooms', 'Bathroom', 'Landsize', 'BuildingArea', 
                    'YearBuilt', 'Lattitude', 'Longtitude']
np.asarray(melbourne_data[melbourne_predictors])
X = melbourne_data[melbourne_predictors]
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
melbourne_model = DecisionTreeRegressor()
melbourne_model.fit(X, y)
```

I am using Jupyter Notebook as part of Anaconda.

The CSV file I am using can be downloaded [here](https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/melbourne-housing-snapshot/data).
Once you do the download the folder you need to extract the files and the csv is inside the folder. You can make your own `melbourne_file_path` based on where the file is for you.

Comment: The error is clear. You have either `float('inf')` or `np.nan` in your dataset. Probably `np.nan`, though. Check with `melbourne_data.isnull().values.any()`

Comment: The output I get is true, so how do I deal with this null data?

Comment: Also if I had `float('inf')`, what does this mean and how do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting is fairly clear: `Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large`. The problem is not that your inputs are pandas Series, but that your data is missing values! A quick glance at your CSV on Kaggle shows that rows 15 and 16 are missing quite a few fields, for example.

It's up to you to decide how to handle these missing values. One way is just to drop any row that's missing 1 or more values: `df.dropna(inplace=True)`. This should get the RandomForestRegressor to fit without errors, but might bias your results if too many rows are dropped. A possibly better approach is to fill missing values with the column mean: `df.fillna(df.mean())`.

Comment: I have used the second command you have told me to use but I get an error telling me that `TypeError: stat_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but your lines `np.asarray(melbourne_data.Price)` and `np.asarray(melbourne_data[melbourne_predictors])` don't do anything, because you're not assigning their output to a variable. The error you're getting suggests you're calling it on a class name without initialization parentheses (`ClassName.mean()` instead of `ClassName().mean()`). Make sure you call `.mean()` not literally on `df`, but on whatever your DataFrame is named.

Comment: I have formatted it like `df.fullna(melbourne_data.mean())` and get `TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type` as an error.

Comment: @HD What is `df` in your code? You have to run `melbourne_data.fillna(melbourne_data.mean())`.